# USB not detecting in UTM Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, apple-m1, virtualization

Hi I have a windows 11 in UTM, and I'm trying to connect a USB to my host (Macbook) it's not detecting in the File explorer of the Widows 11 Virtual Machine (running under UTM)

What should I be doing to detect that? I want to boot from that drive. That would be great if someone knew the boot key for the Windows 11 running under UTM ( MacBook M1 as a HOST)

I tried to check the DISKPART options, but it's not detecting there, I'm not sure what my next troubleshooting step should be.

Answer (score 1):

Looking that you have tried using `diskpart` to list volumes(drives), this should be the issue. To my experience, you need to configure the USB so that it is attached to the Windows 11 Virtual Machine, not your host (macOS).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.getutm.app/guest-support/sharing/usb/),

> Once the virtual machine is started, plug in the device and you should see a prompt to attach the device. You can also press the USB button on the toolbar to see a list of devices which you can attach or detach.